# What's the significance of the shooting star in Jaws?

Tags: analysis, jaws

In the movie [Jaws](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073195/), during the night/early morning scene where  *Hooper*, *Quint* and *Chief Brody* encounter the great white shark (when the shark begins pounding on the boat), just after the shark goes away there's a shooting star in the corner of the scene, and it's shown twice.

What was the significance of this "shooting star"?

Comment: “the” Chief Brody?

Comment: Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foxl-BAtjMU

Comment: I've watched Jaws like 5 times and I never noticed the shooting star.   Cool question with a very cool answer.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**There was actually no significance to the shooting star in the movie.**  It was just a happy accident that was captured on film according to the 1995 documentary [*The Making of Steven Spielberg's Jaws*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0251821/).  This [site](http://fromdirectorstevenspielberg.tumblr.com/post/51555975375/steven-spielberg-questions-why-does-spielberg-use-shooti) explains it in more detail:

> Ironically, Spielberg’s first cinematic shooting star **occurred
>   accidentally rather than by design. In the final act of Jaws, a
>   shooting star can be seen during one of the night sequences, when
>   Brody is loading his gun. However, this wasn’t a special effect.**
>   According to the 1995 documentary ‘The Making of Steven Spielberg’s
>   'Jaws’’, the shooting star occurred naturally, and Spielberg and his
>   crew just happened to be in the right place at the right time to
>   capture it.

Apparently, this happy accident turned into somewhat of a theme in future Spielberg movies involving shooting stars:

> A happy accident it may have been, but it sparked off a reoccurring
>   theme. Along with Close Encounters and Jaws, shooting stars can also
>   be seen in Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom and The Adventures of
>   Tintin: The Secret of the Unicorn. Some have also suggested they’re
>   visible in Hook and Saving Private Ryan, but so far I haven’t been
>   able to find any clear-cut evidence for either.

Comment: Were the recurring shooting stars also natural or were they special effects?

Comment: @wedstrom that sounds like a [new question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)